# not show any picture in full html ,filtered html mode

Tags: media, .htaccess

when i upload or post a link image in article post or basic post not show anything but when i use the img tag and address show image![image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSri9.png)

Comment: As shown in your scrrenshot, you have given full path for image under src tag. But when you upload image through editor, did you check what path is coming inside src tag. Sometimes due to wrong relative path this type of issue comes. Please check through firebug or source code whether img tag is producing or not. Please confirm?

Comment: i saw and there is no img tag in source code :(

Comment: problem solved problem with filtered html configured and tag <img> and <p> is not in filteredhtml tnx

Comment: There is a *reason* there is no `<img>` tag allowed in the "Filtered HTML" text format. If you allow untrusted users to use the `<img>` tag, your site is wide open to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments - try a [module](https://drupal.org/project/insert) that inserts images into the body of a content type.